# How long should it take for gparted to shrink a 44 GB partition down to 10 GB

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I've had gparted running to shrink a Backtrack partition down to 10 GB from 44 GB. I was wondering how long that should take and wether or not it's jammed. It's been on "shrink file system" for well over an hour now.

Comment: A lot of this depends on the hardware involved.  What's the drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A long time.  An hour doesn't surprise me in the least.

The size of the drive matters, the size of the data matters, the bus it's on matters (USB?), the fragmentation of the drive before resizing matters, shifting the data while shrinking it also matters.

It's basically impossible for us to tell you.

I like this quote from [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial152.html#livecd): "The resize process can take a while depending on how big your drive is and how much the partition's size was changed. So, *you may want to go and get a nice cup of tea and relax*."

Comment: Yup, it took about two hours to resize and format to fat32. Thanks anyway :)