# GParted stuck applying operations after copying partition between two disks

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I'm copying a partition I had on a virtual disk (VirtualBox) to a real disk. I ran GParted on the virtual machine and copied the main partition (12.98 GiB) over to the new disk, and during the copy I inflated it to fit the entire disk's space (~500GiB) and leave only 1.8 GiB free for swap.

The first step in the process was to delete the currently existing partition on the disk, and then the copy process started. Now it seems to be completed (the progress bar says "12.98 GiB of 12.98 GiB copied") but the bar has been wiggling around with no sign of progress for the last 20 minutes:

[image: Screenshot of GParted stuck]

What does this mean? Is it safe to terminate the process? Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: How long have you waited?  Repartitioning, resizing, moving etc. that much data could potentially take hours.  See [How long should it take for gparted to shrink a 44 GB partition down to 10 GB](http://superuser.com/questions/258830/how-long-should-it-take-for-gparted-to-shrink-a-44-gb-partition-down-to-10-gb) for similar experiences. ;)

Comment: The copying itself took ~25 minutes. Since then it's been stuck for another good 20 minutes.

Comment: If you notice it says "12.98 GiB of 12.98 GiB copied (00:00:00 remaining)". It has not moved on to the next step in the process.

Comment: Are the drive(s) showing as busy (ie: is the LED on/blinking)?

Comment: No, the led on the external drive is still.

Answer (score 1):

Give it longer than 45 minutes -- Copying is only part of the job, and it's often not the longest part.

Couple random examples:

> "The resize process can take a while depending on how big your drive
>   is and how much the partition's size was changed. So, you may want to
>   go and get a nice cup of tea and relax."

.

> "i moved some partitions around once on an 80gb hard drive. i moved
>   some to the left and some to the right. it took over a day and a half
>   for it to finish. i learned to never move left!"

.

> "I have never resized an entire 250GB filesystem before, but I know
>   that 50-60GBs can take upto 3-4 hours."

Comment: The problem is that it's stuck on the copying step, it hasn't notified me of moving on to any further step.