# Disk Utility has been Shrinking disk for several hours on my MAC OS X 10.7 LION

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, osx-lion, disk-utility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long should it take for gparted to shrink a 44 GB partition down to 10 GB](https://superuser.com/questions/258830/how-long-should-it-take-for-gparted-to-shrink-a-44-gb-partition-down-to-10-gb)

I was trying to make 2 partitions in my local drive of my macbook. Disk Utility has been 'shrinking disk' for several hours and I'm debating if it's hanging. I see no activity on the drive, so I'm not sure what's going on.

How long should this typically take to finish?

I'm just concerned by stopping the 'shrinking disk' while it's in the middle will cause something to corrupt on the drive. How long should I wait before I just force quit Disk Utility? and no I didn't backup my data :)

Thanks

Comment: The answer is pretty simple , Just wait my friend :) it could take up to 5 hours but it's always better to wait rather than having the risk or loosing your data , highly recommend you to go have some beer, to watch Spartacus and then get back when it is finished :)

Comment: If your disk is rather full (especially after shrinking), it can take *very* long. Also, resizing partitions without backup is a really bad idea if you value your data.